# Format X label on mouse hover in chart.js

Tags: chart.js

I'm using Javascrip Date objects for the X label.
I was able to format it properly in the X axis but now I'm struggling to format the label when moving the mouse over each of the bars in the chart.

[image]

How can I change that full date to a custom format?

[Reproduction online](http://jsfiddle.net/prfd1m8q/)

I guess it will have to go in the `ticks` option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit the `title` callback property in your tooltips attribute, stored in the option :

```js
tooltips: {
    callbacks: {
        title: function(tooltipItem, chartData) {
            // You return what you want here
            return "Title";
        }
    }
}
```

You can see [on this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/prfd1m8q/106/) your updated example, and here is its result :

[image]